# Wondering about capabilities of titanium appcelerator?

Tags: java, titanium, crud, titanium-mobile

We have a web application that uses (java/Java EE, Struts, Hibernate) running on Apache tomcat using MySQL as the DB.  It has been up and running for quite a few years, so we have a very large pool of data (millions of row).

We need to convert this web app to a mobile application (cross platform, ios, Android), so we've decided to use the Titanium Appcelerator.

I have quite a few concerns before implementation:

1. I've heard that titanium gives you very good gui, but what about the functionality? What happens when a user clicks a buttons (sending/retrieving data from db)?
   Can I use java to handle this??
2. I have seen examples of interacting through database, but approx all are using PHP as as a server side language, but nobody knows PHP here.
   Though our team has some android exp(all sort of JSON, small client app), I am not sure whether it would be helpful.
3. Out goal is to convert a huge CRUD web app to a cross platform mobile app (I dont want to lose java on the server).  Can Titanium appcelerator handle this?

Answer (score 0):

See the App as something separate. It doesn't matter what is on the other end, as long as you get either JSON or XML (or something else if you prefer).

Titanium Appcelerator is a JavaScript tool that can handle (both build-in) JSON and XML.

To answer your questions:

1: Functionality is really good. It cannot be done by Java, but you'll get events (in JavaScript) which handles click/swipe/press/doubleclick etc. Events are always defined in the Documentation. In your case, the [button](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Button-object). You can see what events it can handle there, and what properties you can set.

An example from the docs page adding a button, and having the click event.

```
var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
   title: 'Hello',
   top: 10,
   width: 100,
   height: 50
});
button.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
   Titanium.API.info("You clicked the button");
});
```

2: Whatever server side language you use, as long as you export usable content (JSON/XML) it is useable by Titanium. It acts like a client. No need to worry there.

3: as answered above, you can do everything with it you want. On server side you only need to write an API which can handle everything.

I hope this will take away your concerns. If you need more help on other questions, just enter a new question on SO and I'll see them pass by.

Comment: We have servlets/java to handle server side scripts in a pure web app , we can create a good looking gui by titanium (javascript),however , can we use java to handle all db(MYSQL) interaction. as well as we want to write all (after clicking blah buttun) with java ..is it possible??..we dont want to use php , python , ROR..?

Comment: Java as serverside is fine. You'll just have to set up the communication between serverside and the App. No Java in the app, or mysql talk in the App. You'll have to create a webservice for it

Comment: can not do without webservice?  for example in php we can do like                                                                                                    loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if (username.value != '' && password.value != '')
     {
 loginReq.open("POST","http://192.168.30.2/post_auth.php");  
  var params = {
   username: username.value,
   password: password.value
  };
  loginReq.send(params);
      }
      else
      {
 alert("Username/Password are required");
      }
});

Comment: sure you can create an app without webservice. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: we have a web application project,we have build using java servlete(java ,jsp,struts,hiberrnet,mysql) already using this product. so now same application some module we are going to build for mobile application,so we are using titanium android ,  we ned to build connection between titanium javscript to our server database(mysql) so we are looking to write server side application by using java,because already running appache serever in our server so i need to know how to build connection ( i googled,  most of example used php only but i need to by using java servelet

Comment: Don't connect to MySQL from the device! Especially not on android, but sure as hell not on iPhone either. The users of the app (at least, the technical ones) will be able to grab out the username/password. You really should build a webservice inbetween

Comment: thanks for all info ,  could u please provide any sample app , or links to achieve it ,  I've never build any web service before , any good link to get up  and running...i have once use axis 2 and build a toy app , will it work

Comment: It's hard to explain it to you simple. Try and google for webservice & JSON. (and CRUD if you need it). For implementation in the app look at httpclient: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object. If you have other questions, please add new questions (not add it to the comments here)

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by Topener, Titanium is able to handle your requirements. I'd like to point out something more fundamental:

> We need to convert this web app to a mobile application (..), **so** we've decided to use the Titanium Appcelerator.

I'm somewhat surprised by this reasoning, kinda "We needed a car, **so** we decided to buy a Nissan." Why not a Ford, a Holden or a Porsche?

There are in fact well over 30 technologies claiming to be able to do cross-platform mobile development. I took a deep look at 16 of them during the course of last year for my master's thesis.

I'd suggest you have a look two other technologies as well. Why? You are converting a web app to a mobile app. Why not consider a framework that allows you to write your app's UI using web technologies? You might be able to port some of the existing UI-code, after all.

- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (free, now owned by Adobe): You implement the entire app in JavaScript, basically as a WebApp, but you get a native, installable binary that can be distributed using the AppStores. Easy to combine with a SenchaTouch HTML5-UI.
- [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/) (free, now owned by Motorola Systems): You implement the UI in HTML5 and the logic in Ruby. Rhodes provides a **really good** Object-Mapper and Sync capabilities. As you seem to have quite a bit of data to handle, this could provide a significant advantage over Titanium's SQLite Database. Learning the bits of ruby should not cost you more than a week or so.

If you definitely **need** a native UI, then the [AQUA-Framework](http://uxplus.com/) might be worth a look... but I havn't tested that one.